# Convert String to Carbon

Tags: php, date, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 5.1

Few days ago I used `protected $dates = ['license_expire']` in my model to convert the string date to Carbon instances. In HTML the default value in create form for the date was `Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')`

In order to show alert in home page i used `<p>Licence Expired: <b>{{ $employee->license_expire < Carbon\Carbon::now()?'License has expired':$employee->license_expire->diffForHumans() }}</b></p>`

Till then diffForHumans() method works fine.

But in that case the edit form's default value also was today's date no matter what was in database(I am using a partial form). To resolve it I change the default value in HTML was NUll. And add another method in my model to show current date in create form.

```
public function getLicenseExpireAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

After that when i go to home page i have an `FatalErrorException` which says `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string`

When I check the date with `dd($employee->license_expire)` it become STRING again.

Can anybody tell me how can I convert the string to Carbon in this situation?

or

Make my create form's default date as today's date, the edit form's date from database and I can use diffForHumans() to show alert in home page?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You were almost there.

Remove `protected $dates = ['license_expire']`

and then change your `LicenseExpire` accessor to:

```
public function getLicenseExpireAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

This way it will return a `Carbon` instance no matter what.
So for your form you would just have `$employee->license_expire->format('Y-m-d')` (or whatever format is required) and `diffForHumans()` should work on your home page as well.

---

If you're using Laravel 9+, you can alternatively use the updated syntax for defining [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

public function licenseExpire(): Attribute 
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => Carbon::parse($value);
    );
}
```

Comment: yes! it helped. i did exactly what you said. it works perfectly as i desire.

Answer (score 22):

Why not try using the following:

```
$dateTimeString = $aDateString." ".$aTimeString;
$dueDateTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTimeString, 'Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 0):

$filter['dateOfService']='06.2021';

```
$d1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('m.Y', $filter['dateOfService'], 'Europe/Warsaw')->format('m.Y');
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
$date = Carbon::parse(date_format($youttimestring,'d/m/Y H:i:s'));
echo $date;
```